# Is it more efficient to load or tow a vehicle?

Tags: forces, friction, drag

If I had a truck (a U-haul or similar) and needed to move a four-wheeled car from one location to another, would it require less energy (fuel) to load the car into the truck or tow it behind?

A friend and I are debating this question (without any need for its practical application) and have it boiled down to whether the extra weight from loading or the extra drag/friction from towing would have a greater impact on forward forces.

Comment: If I've tagged this poorly, please modify the tags, as I'm no physicist.

Comment: I don't think this can be answered because if depends on variables that we don't have e.g. how much extra friction the towed car produces. The only reliable way to do this would be to try the experiment, and even then you might get differing results with different types of trucks and car.

Comment: Thought experiments to prove John's claim:  If you towed the car really far behind, you would have twice the drag, so the distance between the car and the truck matters.  If you were on weak ground, and you put the car in the truck, the added pressure on the tires could cause you to have to slog through the ground instead of going over it.  However, in ideal situations, I'd like to point out that this is almost exactly what trains do!

Comment: [Last time I moved, I got the Knight Rider treatment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX8Jd.jpg). Do not regret.

Answer (score 2):

To be serious we can start tomorrow :-)

Three points for the car insight the truck:

- The friction and the air turbulences from the two cars will be higher then from the truck and the car insight.
- It is enough to drive the truck with one person, for the towed care you need a driver more.
- you will not crash the car into the truck and you'll not lose the tow overdriving it.

The only point for the tow is not really a good one because you can do it with the car in truck too:

- You will drive careful and you'll try to brake as little as possible.

Good luck